# case statement not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't undestand. What is Test1 in the following example?:

```
class Test1
  def request
    Test2.new.get_request(self.class)
  end
end

class Test2
  def get_request(klass)
    p klass # => Test1

    case klass
    when Test1
      p 'Test1 is class'
    when "Test1"
      p 'Test1 is string'
    when :Test1
      p 'Test1 is sybol'
    else
      p 'wtf is klass ????'
    end
  end
end

Test1.new.request
# Test1
# "wtf is klass ????"
```

(It works if `self.class` change to `self`)
But what is explanation of this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is that in case of CASE statement the comparison the check is a === where as in if it is ==. SO if you had

`p "GOT IT" if klass == Test1`

It would have worked, where as doing

`p "GOT IT" if klass === Test1`

Will not yield the print statment.

In short the comparison is done by comparing the object in the when-clause with the object in the case-clause using the === operator and not == hence the TEST1 value in klass variable does not compare with === (case stmt).

To add more clarity to this case :

```
1.8.7 :074 > Test1.new.class == Test1
 => true 
1.8.7 :075 > Test1.new.class === Test1
 => false
```

Second one happens for case/when statement

Comment: The comparison is done the other way round, i.e. `Test1 === Test1.new.class`. Passing an instance (i.e. `self` instead of `self.class`) works as expected: `Test1 === Test1.new` is `true`

Answer (score 2):

In a case expression, the when-clauses are compared to the case value with the `===` operator. It is equivalent to this:

```
if Test1 === klass
  p 'Test1 is class'
elsif "Test1" === klass
  p 'Test1 is string'
elseif :Test1 === klass
  p 'Test1 is sybol'
else
  p 'wtf is klass ????'
end
```

The reason it doesn't work the way you want is because `Class#===` is implemented to test whether the right operand *is an instance of* the class. It's meant to make it convenient to do case expressions based on the class of an object. But here it falls down, because you're not actually trying to determine the object's class. Since Test1 isn't an instance of itself — it's an instance of Class — that test yields false.

I think the best you'll get if you actually need to test class identity in a case expression is something like `when ->k{ k == Test1 }`, but it's just kind of an awkward case for the language.